# javascript adding object into other object after the same property _id

Tags: javascript

```
    var selector = {
    "selector": {
        "_id": {
            "$exists": true,
        }
    }
};
```

I have this and I want to add other properties inside "selector" through params like this (I want to always keep "_id:{"$exists:true"}" property and add more after _id, but _id has to always stay):

```
var selector = {
    "selector": {
        "_id": {
            "$exists": true,
        },
        "another":param,
        "another2":param,
    }
};
```

What is the best/cleanest way to do this?? Thank you so much!!

Comment: `selector.selector.yourProperty = yourValue`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yup... it's late at night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an assignment to a property:

```
selector.selector.another = param;
selector.selector.another2 = param;
```

Example:

```js
var selector = {
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$exists": true,
    }
  }
};
console.log("Before");
console.log(selector);
selector.selector.another = "first";
selector.selector.another2 = "second";
console.log("After");
console.log(selector);
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i thought it wasnt simple like that!! SORRY

Answer (score 0):

I like jquery extends a lot.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/
`$.extend( selector, {param1: value1, param2: value2} );`

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing same is:

```js
var selector = {
    "selector": {
        "_id": {
            "$exists": true,
        }
    }
}
var dynamicProperty = "another"
selector.selector[dynamicProperty] = 123;

console.log(selector)
```

plus it is dynamic too.